# If there are an infinite number of solutions to the system

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm confused on how to solve this..

If there are an infinite number of solutions to the system

$7x + 8y = h$

$6x + ky = -10$

then $k = ? $ and $h = ?$

would they both be equal to $0$ ?

Comment: Hint: A 2-variable, 2-equation, linear system has infinitely many solutions if and only if each equation defines the same line.

Comment: how to i define them to be hte same line

Comment: The same you can define any line. Either with a point and slope or with two points. Hint: try using slope of the first line (which does not depend on $h$ first to solve for $k$).

Comment: oh k = 49/7, h = -70/6

Comment: $k\neq \frac{49}{7}$, what is the slope of the top equation?

Comment: typo, meant k = 48/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$7 = 6/7 * 7$

$k = 8 * 6/7 = 48/7$

$-10 = 6/7h \implies h = -70/6$

Answer (score 5):

A system has infinitely many solutions when it is consistent and the number of variables is more than the number of nonzero rows in the row-reduced form of the matrix.
So first do row reduction for the system of equations:$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}7&8&h\\6&k&-10\end{array}\right]\Rightarrow\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1&8-k&h-10\\6&k&-10\end{array}\right]\Rightarrow\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1&8-k&h-10\\0&-48+7k&-6h+50\end{array}\right]$$
In order to have infinitely many solutions, Row $2$ should be a zero row.
Therefore, $$-48+7k=0$$$$-6h+50=0$$
$$k=\frac{48}{7},h=\frac{50}{6}$$

Comment: Should be $+10$ when subtracted eqn. 2 from eqn. 1, not $-10$.

Comment: h is wrong. should be -70/6

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on what this means from @Jay " the number of variables is more than the number of nonzero rows"

Comment: @Shammy you did cut off an important part of that quote. You need reduced row form.  Another way to think about it is that the matrix $A$ in $Ax=b$ will have a nontrivial kernel (if you haven't learned that yet, you will later), meaning that it maps certain vectors to zero. Thus you can add in any multiple of those vectors to a solution hence creating infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the system defined by the two lines,

$$y = m_1 x + b_1$$
$$y = m_2 x + b_2$$

If there are infinitely many solutions, the two lines are the same: $m_1 = m_2$ and $b_1 = b_2$.

If there are no solutions, then the two lines have the same slope but intersect the y-axis at different points: $m_1 = m_2$ but $b_1 \neq b_2$.

If there is exactly one solution, then the two lines do not have the same slope: $m_1 \neq m_2$.